# WooCommerce replace "Available on backorder" in cart/checkout based on product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I wrote some code for displaying a custom backorder message on the product detail page which is based on the product category.

```php
function custom_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {

        if( has_term( 'bridal-line', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            $text = __( 'Your piece will be handcrafted for you. Upon order we will manufacture your piece of eternity. Sadly, we can not give you a timeline, due to Covid 19, but are expecting 5-7 weeks', 'text-domain' );
        }else {
            $text = __( 'This product is currently out of stock, but upon order we will handcraft your piece. Sadly, we can not give you a timeline, due to Covid 19, but are expecting 6-8 week.', 'text-domain' );
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Right now, on the cart page "Available on backorder" gets displayed. How can I show the right backorder message there?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use: [`woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart.php#L92)

> Note that the third parameter (`$product_id`) is specified by [`has_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/), 
>   this is because default the current post(ID) is used. However, if there are several products in the shopping cart, there are multiple IDs...

```php
// Change backorder notification - Single product page
function custom_availability_text( $text, $product ) {
    // Returns whether or not the product is stock managed.
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        // Check if the current post has any of given terms.
        if( has_term( 'bridal-line', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            $text = __( 'My first text', 'woocommerce' );
        } else {
            $text = __( 'My second text', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_availability_text', 10, 2 );

// Change backorder notification - Shop page
function custom_cart_item_backorder_notification( $html, $product_id ){
    // Check if the current post has any of given terms.
    if ( has_term( 'bridal-line', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $html = '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'My first text', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
    } else {
        $html = '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'My second text', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', 'custom_cart_item_backorder_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This code in my theme's `function.php` works for me:

```
function change_specific_availability_text( $availability ) {

    $targeted_text = __( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' );

    if ($availability[ 'class' ] == 'available-on-backorder' && $availability[ 'availability' ] == $targeted_text) {

        $availability[ 'availability' ] = __( 'In the central warehouse', 'your-theme-textdomain' );

    }

    return $availability;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_specific_availability_text', 20, 1 );
```

or alternative, simplified way:

```
function change_specific_availability_text( $availability ) {

    if ($availability[ 'class' ] == 'available-on-backorder') {

        $availability[ 'availability' ] = __( 'In the central warehouse', 'your-theme-textdomain' );

    }

    return $availability;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_specific_availability_text', 20, 1 );
```